# How to write an HTML dropdown menu data to MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to write an HTML dropdown data onto the MySQL database.

I have the following HTML form:

```
<body>
 <form method="post" action="test.php">
  <h3>Name:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="Name">

  <h3>Choose an Interest</h3>
  <select name="Interests" style="width: 400px !important; min-width: 400px; max-width: 400px;">
      <option value="">Choose an option</option>
      <option value="kings">Adroring Kings</option>
      <option value="europe">Travelling Across Europe</option>
      <option value="poland">Poland's Work of Art</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</body>
```

And the following PHP file to connect to my database:

```
<?php

// database connection code
// $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'database_user', 'database_password','database');
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','test');

// get the post records
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$interests= $_POST['Interests'];

// database insert SQL code
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test_data` (`Name`, `Interests`) VALUES ('$name', '$interests')";

// insert in database
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if($rs){
    echo "Contact Records Inserted";
}

?>
```

My SQL is connected and working fine when I just enter a name. However, when I select an option from the dropdown box, the data I enter does not get through to the database anymore.

My database:

[image]

Comment: Nothing jumps out. What is in `$_POST` when you `var_dump()` it as part of your debugging? You need to read up on prepared statements rather than just concatenating strings into a query like that, for various reasons. When you select something from the drop-down, does it still write the name, or does the query fail completely?

Comment: Your code is suseptable to SQL Injection. Switch to parameterized queries. Also, turn on error messages, and sql error messages. That should give you an idea where the problem lies.

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks. I tried my best to avoid the SQL Injection, I guess I was going in the wrong direction. I will modify my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the selected values in the database using PHP you have to perform the tasks described below. I would strongly encourage to use PDO whenever possible rather than mysqli. I will show how to use both.

#### 1. Read the submitted data

When a user submits a form the values will be populated in super global arrays. If your HTML form is set to POST method then the values will be present in `$_POST`. However, you should always make sure that the values were actually submitted when the script runs. You can check that using `isset()` function.

```
// method 1
if(isset($_POST['Name'], $_POST['Interests'])) {
    // your code
}
```

## 2. Establish a connection to the database

Each time the script needs to perform some operations in the database it must have an open connection. This step is important to ensure that the data can be properly transferred. You must always ensure 3 things: enable error reporting, open connection, and set the correct charset.

Using PDO:

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4", 'user', 'pass', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);
```

Using mysqli:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

## 3. Execute prepared statement

Whenever you need to perform an operation you should always use prepared statements. The huge advantage of prepared statements is that they send the data separately from the command and the two can't mix accidently.

Using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `test_data` (`Name`, `Interests`) VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->execute([
    $_POST['Name'],
    $_POST['Interests']
]);
```

Using mysqli:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `test_data` (`Name`, `Interests`) VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['Name'], $_POST['Interests']);
$stmt->execute();
```

That is all that is needed to insert simple data into a MySQL table.